# How much time iwll take me to reach Calculus 3?

Tags: calculus

I currently know the basics of algebra and geometry, like the complete basics. In algebra I know the identities, radicals, and powers. In geometry I only know the basics, just a couple of theorems. I don't even know trigonometry yet. I plan on studying math till I finish calculus 3, how much time would that take if I study 2hrs everyday?

Comment: Nobody could give you an answer to your question. It takes most students three semesters at university to get all the way through Calc 3. That's assuming roughly 3 hours a week in class time and up to 10 hours a week outside class homework for 36 weeks (three 12 week semseters). If you are self studying you can expect it to take longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on how much you know, how much you want to know, how quickly you learn, and how well you retain what you have learned.  The answer will be different for everyone.

For classes trying to get everyone through a standard curriculum, you encounter Algebra I, Geometry, Algebra II, Trigonometry/Precalculus, Calculus I, Calculus II, and Calculus III. Each class takes a year if you are in high school and half a year if you are in college.

Also, what counts as "calculus III" varies dramatically with the college.  MIT doesn't have a calculus III, it has differential equations as the third math course.  But I have seen colleges with Calculus I through IV that doesn't cover as much.  Different classes will cover things in different amounts of depth.  If you want total mastery that will obviously take longer to achieve.

So a more specific answer will depend on you, especially what you consider "calculus III" and how well you want to know it, in addition to the other things I mentioned.

Comment: "calculus III" varies dramatically with the college: right. I would say Calculus III is Vectorial Analysis and an introduction to differential geometry of curves and surfaces, i.e. Marsden & Tromba's book, whereas DEs and transforms is often named "ampliación" (extension) in Spain.

Answer (score 0):

I've rigorously self-studied through high school and Calc 1 and 2 to complete mastery. I take past exams online for them now and then to keep in check (averaging 98%+).

I recently took notes on all of Calc 3 this summer and am currently trying to completely master it too (know all of it and without forgetting). I use this method of taking notes and then mastering with problems, tests, and memorization for thing other than math too.

**Now to the point.** It took me 3 years to get from where you are to where I am now, so believe in yourself and you can do it too. I study math at most 2 hrs per day, so your devotion will pay off.